# Kivy: crossplatform notification icon

Tags: android, python, linux, notifications, kivy

I want to create a cross-platform application (Ubuntu and Android) with a notification icon. Is there a standard way to create such an app using Kivy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, no… if you want to define such an API and implement it using platform-specific libs (libnotify on Ubuntu, and pyjnius on Android), that would be welcomed though. Others will help make it work on other platforms.